# Asana API Fetching tasks in date range - PHP

Tags: php, asana-api

I have tried alot but didn't found any parameter to call the only data I need from Asana API .

I need data in date range.

I have to fetch all the data and than need to filter according my need.

This is very painful.

Answer (score 0):

Add your need option fields

```
# Request
curl -u <api_key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/1224?opt_fields=name,notes"

# Response
HTTP/1.1 200
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Make a list",
    "notes": "Check it twice!",
    "id": 1224
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there is any way to use complete_since and completed parameter together ?
I just want all the completed tasks